# Need help to convert html template to code igniter

Tags: codeigniter, templates

Hi guys i am learning code igniter of my own. can you help me how to integrate the template in code igniter

Answer (score 2):

You can use a template library, like this one by [Williams Concepts](http://williamsconcepts.com/ci/codeigniter/libraries/template/).

It is easy to follow and has some nice features like adding extra js/css on a per request basis.